# 404 error while calling two rest api services

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I wanted to request two api services- one to get the list of users of the site using this api: `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')` and based on the response wanted to call another api: `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='accountname'` to list the birthdays of all the users using a for loop.

I got the response for the first api in the console but second api returns 404 not found. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using SharePoint online, the 2nd REST call would be like:

```
https://site-collection-url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|gautam@tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com'
```

But if you are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise, the REST call would be like:

```
https://site-collection-url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'
```